# Running background threads that include blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a singleton that loads up an a bunch of ALAssets when my app launches. This is causing the main thread to freeze for more then 10 seconds while it loads each image into memory. Obviously a big no no.

I tried to put it on a background thread, but it only partially executes.

```
+ (CCPhotos*) sharedPhotos
{
    static CCPhotos* shared = nil;

    if (!shared)
    {
        shared = [[CCPhotos alloc] init];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [shared loadPhotosArray];
        });

    }

    return shared;
}


- (void) loadPhotosArray
{
    NSLog(@"Loading photos");
    _photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSData* data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"savedImages"];
    if (data)
    {
        NSArray* storedUrls = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data]];

        // reverse array
        NSArray* urls = [[storedUrls reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

        for (NSURL* assetUrl in urls)
        {
            NSLog(@"Looking up %@", assetUrl);

            // Block to handle image handling success
  // This initializes, but doesn't get called
 ////-->>      
           ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
            {
                ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
                CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];
                if (iref) {
                    UIImage* tempImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
                    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: tempImage.CGImage scale: 1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];

                    // Set image in imageView
                    [_photos addObject: image];
                    NSLog(@"Added photo with url: %@", [rep url]);
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"PhotosChanged" object: self];
                }
            };

            // Handles failure of getting image
            ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
            {
                NSLog(@"Can't get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
            };

            // Load image then call appropriate block
            ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [assetslibrary assetForURL: assetUrl
                           resultBlock: resultblock
                          failureBlock: failureblock];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Photo storage is empty");
    }
}
```

I've narrowed down the problem to `ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock` which doesn't get called. Multiple threads spawn at the beginning, and each one gets to this line, initializes the result block, but doesn't call it. I think it has to do with the thread safety on the block. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this when you post the notification:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"PhotosChanged" object: self];
});
```

I believe the reason it is not working for you is because this is not being called on the main thread. All UI changes/updates (which I am assuming this leads to) must be executed on the main thread. This will force the notification to happen on the necessary thread and should work properly!

This is a pretty common thing to do. I actually created a code snippet because I found myself typing this out so often:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    <#on back thread#>
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        <#on main thread#>
    });
});
```

I then set the completion short cut to `dispatch_async`

Comment: Maybe I phrased my question poorly, but the issue is the entire `ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock` which doesn't get called

Comment: Ah, does it call the failure block? Or just no block at all?

Comment: Neither are called. They're called properly when I do `[shared loadPhotosArray]` without spawning it in a new thread. Also, thanks for that snippet :) It will definitely come in handy, I'm trying to learn all about threading.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding, you are spinning up multiple instances of your singleton.  In that case you will probably want to put a `@synchronized` block in there.  For example:

```
+ (CCPhotos*) sharedPhotos
{
  static CCPhotos* shared = nil;

  @synchronized ([CCPhotos class])
  {
     if (!shared)
     {
         shared = [[CCPhotos alloc] init];

         dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

         dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [shared loadPhotosArray];
         });

     }
  }

  return shared;
}
```

Hope that helps.